# TransactionScope() and parallel query execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, parallel-processing, transactions

We're trying to run parallel queries inside a transaction scope to improve performance of our code. We have several changes to be made in the database that have no connection to each other. We could run the code like this:

```
using(var tran = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    await queryMethod1Async();
    await queryMethod2Async();
    await queryMethod3Async();

    tran.Complete();
}
```

however, since the methods are independent of each other, we would like to run the code like this:

```
using(var tran = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    tasks.Add(queryMethod1Async());
    tasks.Add(queryMethod2Async());
    tasks.Add(queryMethod3Async());

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    tran.Complete();
}
```

We are running into some issues with the parallel execution:

- Running the queries in parallel seems to escalate the transaction. During escalation, sometimes an error occurs:

```
The wait operation timed out  --> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.    
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.Promote() --> Failure while attempting to promote transaction.    
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.Promote()     
at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx)     
at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx) --> The transaction has aborted.    
at System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.CheckForFinishedTransaction(InternalTransaction tx)     
at System.Transactions.Transaction.Promote()     
at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.ConvertToOletxTransaction(Transaction transaction)    
at System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.GetTransactionCookie(Transaction transaction, Byte[] whereAbouts)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)     
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
```

After some investigation, this seems to be because during escalation, the original connection for the transaction is used, but during parallel execution, this connection might be in use.
I've tried to enable [MARS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/features/using-multiple-active-result-sets-mars?view=sql-server-ver15) to avoid this issue, but this results in a different error:

```
Current Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) transaction must be committed by remote client.    
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso, SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)     
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDelegatedTransaction.SinglePhaseCommit(SinglePhaseEnlistment enlistment) --> The transaction has aborted.
```

To clarify, each of the above methods create a new sqlconnection, and we have configured MSDTC correctly

I'm not sure why this second error occurs, but I have a feeling I'm going about this the wrong way. Is it possible to do parallel query execution inside a transaction scope, and if so, what is the right way to go about this?

Comment: With all respect, the correct wording ought be ***"concurrent** query execution"*, as the scope of the TransactionScope()-context-manager just finally injects a "macro"-structure barrier, for all async-"just"-[CONCURRENT] tasks to sit and wait for the slowest, before the code-execution can only later leave the scope. Such manual syncing-barrier for principally asynchronous, "just"-[CONCURRENT] operations of independent, otherwise uncoordinated tasks is not property of the context + not True-[PARALLEL] problem, just an "exit-ALAP barrier" enforcing wait till all "just"-[CONCURRENT] flows finish

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to do parallel query execution inside a transaction scope, and if so, what is the right way to go about this?

Yes.  You must you a separate SqlConnection for each query, and have MSDTC properly configured and running.  But it's rarely useful to do this, as each command can be run in parallel on SQL Server, so running multiple commands at the same time often doesn't decrease the overall runtime.

Comment: We already create a separate SqlConnection for each query, and MSDTC is configured correctly, but we are still getting the above error. I also disagree with the statement that it is rarely useful. I understand that each command can be run in parallel on sql server, but when the next command is sent to sql server ony when the previous command is finished, nothing is run in parallel

Comment: Well that _should_ work, but MSTDC can be tricky to troubleshoot.  You might consider using 3 separate transactions and committing them all after they've all finished.

Comment: Having 3 separate transactions defeats the purpose of using transactions. I need to have ALL actions done, or none of them. But I can still assure to you we have MSDTC configured correctly. We are running an enterprise saas environment for hundreds of customers and have already been using msdtc for a decade

Comment: The idea of separate transactions is that it's very unlikely that a Sql Server trasaction will fail when you try to commit it (unless you are using In-Memory OLTP).  Any failures should happen before any attempted commit, and in time to rollback all of the transactions.  So if MTDTC is working, can you simplify the code into a repro and add it to your question?

Comment: I understand your idea now, but do I understand correctly is that your conclusion is that doing parallel queries in a single transaction should not be done? I'm quite surprised if this is not "supported" and I need to completely change the setup of my code to run parallel transaction to accomplish this. This would make the code a lot more complicated and difficult to understand/maintain

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better that you create procedure in your database that run all queries in it.
then you can get it in one request with dataset.
now use each datatable in dataset at its place.

Answer (score 0):

You can try few options:

1. With MARS enabled, create your transaction scope with TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled parameter:

```
using(var tran = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled)
{...
```

I used System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection with dapper to read / write data and it worked.

2. If you are using Entity Framework Core, you can use SemaphoreSlim to synchronize access to your DbContext to avoid this problem. Example:

```
// declare semaphore
var syncSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
// [...]
// and use it in all your async functions like this:
async Task queryMethod1Async()
{
    await syncSemaphore.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
       // Use your database connection - read or write and release semaphore so other tasks can access
    }
    finally
    {
        syncSemaphore.Release();
    }            
}
```

Comment: We already have the asyncflowoption enabled, and all our queries that use entity framework use their own instance of a dbcontext. But in this example non of the queries in the transaction use entity framework

Answer (score 0):

Is any of your `queryMethodXAsync` spawning it's own Transaction (as neasted transaction) and does not rollback or commit it before you try to complete the `TransactionScope`

Things like that could happen if you call stored procedure that uses transactions inside of it and does not dispose in the correct way of it.

Do you have an InnerExcpetion in your exception with more details?